# Select DISTINCT, GROUP BY, HAVING count(*) in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following scope:

```
public function scopeFilterByAmenities($query, AmenityFilters $amenities)
{        
    $ids = DB::table('property_amenities')->distinct()
        ->where(function($query) use ($amenities){
            $query->whereIn('amenity_id', $amenities->ids_enabled());
            $query->where('status', $amenities->enabled_value);
        })
        ->orWhere(function($query) use ($amenities){
            $query->whereIn('amenity_id', $amenities->ids_disabled());
            $query->where('status', $amenities->disabled_value);
        })
        ->groupBy('property_id')
        ->havingRaw('count(*) = '.$amenities->count()) // sum of $amenities->ids_enabled() and $amenities->ids_disabled()
        ->pluck('property_id');

    return $query->whereIn('id', $ids);
}
```

Shouldn't be any easier way by using the Laravel ORM to return the same results? I've managed to do in this way but looks messy from my perspective, so does Laravel have something built in so can make the things more clear?

Comment: It's never right to use both `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY`. If you group the results, you can't possibly get any duplicates, so `DISTINCT` is redundant.

Comment: Sure, you're right, didn't thought on that, tho I saw this example query on multiple websites.